# Renewal of passport (with ECNR) with alternate documentation

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india, paperwork, ecr

I have to get my passport renewed with ECNR marked as yes and for this I have to produce 10th Passing certificate. But I just have the 10th Mark sheet and not the passing certificate. So will I be allowed to apply with mark sheet only? Please let me know.

One more thing on the passport site http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/pdf/ApplicationformInstructionBooklet-V3.0.pdf

they have mentioned that we can also produce professional degree and since I have done B-TECH so can I produce the B-tech degree instead of 10th passing certificate?

Answer (score 2):

As per the same link, refer `Section B Column 2.15`. Professional degree certificate is enough or even the 10th grade marksheet is enough for ECNR.

> `<Column 2.15 - Are you eligible for Non-ECR Category? >`
>
> j) All professional degree holders, their spouses and dependent
>   children. Examples of professional degree holders are Doctors holding
>   MBBS degree or equivalent degree in Ayurved or Homeopathy